# serial communication through rs232 in linux c

Tags: c, linux

I am new in Linux. I am facing problem in serial communications.
I have two computers, one is running a hyper terminal and on another I am writing a C program to communicate with hyper terminal. Both PC are connected through RS232.
I have written some code and I am able to send data to hyper terminal, but I am not sure how I can read data from hyper terminal with a program written in C on a Linux PC.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct termios options;
    int fd;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not open port /dev/ttyS0\n");
        return 1;
    }

    tcgetattr(fd, &options); //get port options

    cfsetispeed(&options, B9600); //set input baud rate
    cfsetospeed(&options, B9600); //set output baud rate

    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); //enable receiver and set local mode

    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; //disable hardware flow control
    options.c_cflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ISIG); //set raw input

    options.c_cflag |= IXOFF; //disable software flow control

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options); //set new port options

    sleep(1);
    int rc,count;
    int size = 8;
    unsigned char buf[10];
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char ch;
    int i=0;
    printf("enter the data you want to send");

    while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        write(fd,&ch,1);
    }
    close(fd);

    printf("Finished.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the part communicating with the Hyper terminal?  Partially the part of where you are trying to read data.

Comment: @Glenn thanks for ur respone....that what i have given you is able to do communication with hyper terminal. i.e one way communication.when i run this code i am able to send data from linux box to hyper terminal...i am facing problem how to get data when i send data from hyper terminal to linux PC.

Comment: I would use **read** [link] http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html on the File Descriptor to get the data from the Hyper Term, similar to the write you have to send data.  I believe the read should block until there is data.  If not, you can use **select** to determine if there is data to be read.

Comment: What's wrong with read()? Also you can take code from picocom as a reference.